# how to use counter on dictonary values are list items

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, counter

My defaultdict is as follows:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'DrJillStein': [18021496, 30576467, 35175054, 122130797, 227720229, 289019104, 441389311, 456794981, 774180818,763849988988211200], 'realDonaldTrump': [14669951, 22203756, 41634520, 50769180, 75541946, 245963716, 475802156, 2325495378, 720293443260456960, 729676086632656900], 'GovGaryJohnson': [15232635, 19089116, 22330739, 29255194, 44776017, 47490022, 51752944, 73206956, 90573676, 366743017], 'HillaryClinton': [15972271, 34782406, 113298560, 115740215, 325886383, 582037089, 802430450, 3044781131, 729761993461248000, 734768872625188864]})
```

It contains `use_name` and then a list of ids, in short -> key = user and value = list of ids.

I wanted first to find out common ids and then to find out the most 5 common ids in all dict, like:
if 
    id =14669951, 15513604, 22203756

then there occurrences like:

```
{[14669951:2][15513604:4][22203756:7]}
```

Guide me how to do that on python 3.5 or on greater version.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize a `Counter` from `collections` and ask for the 5 `most_common`.

In order to initialize the `Counter` just provide it with a comprehension:

```
c = Counter(v for sub in d.values() for v in sub)
```

I added an extra `id` to your `defaultdict` to get a count of `2` for one of them. The result can be obtained with `c.most_common(5)`:

```
c.most_common(5)
[(14669951, 2),
 (720293443260456960, 1),
 (763849988988211200, 1),
 (366743017, 1),
 (245963716, 1)]
```